# Open a local HTML file using window.open in Chrome

Tags: javascript

I want to open a local HTML file through Javascript using:

```
window.open ("file://C:/Users/wins/Desktop/exclusiveWordpress.html","mywindow");
```

But it is opening a new window with a blank page as we used to get when URL is not specified. How do I achieve this?

Comment: try `file:///` instead of `file://`

Comment: Is the page with this HTML on `file:` protocol as well?

Comment: ya its a html file. I have tries with file:/// instead of file://.........still its not working as expected

Comment: If the original web page is coming from http{s}, you can't (security issues).  Could you specify where the javascript is being run from (localhost, http://, https://, file://, ... telling us that its an html file is not specific enough)

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me fine:

File 1:

```
    <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <a href="#" onclick="window.open('file:///D:/Examples/file2.html'); return false">CLICK ME</a>
    </body>
    <footer></footer>
    </html>
```

File 2:

```
    <html>
        ...
    </html>
```

This method works regardless of whether or not the 2 files are in the same directory, BUT both files must be local.

For obvious security reasons, if File 1 is located on a remote server you **absolutely cannot** open a file on some client's host computer and trying to do so will open a blank target.

Comment: how to open it in the same tab?

Comment: @TusharGogna by passing the function the `name` attribute like: `window.open('file:///D:/Examples/file2.html', "_self")`;

Comment: Thanks (y) although I now did that using location.harif. Anyways, Happy new year :)

Comment: This method will not work if we open then html though server. Only works when opening it as **file:///D:/Examples/file1.html**

Answer (score 1):

`window.location.href = 'file://///fileserver/upload/Old_Upload/05_06_2019/THRESHOLD/BBH/Look/chrs/Delia';`

Nothing Worked for me.

Answer (score -4):

First, make sure that the source page and the target page are both served through the `file` URI scheme. You can't force an `http` page to open a `file` page (but it works the other way around).

Next, your script that calls `window.open()` should be invoked by a user-initiated event, such as clicks, keypresses and the like.  Simply calling `window.open()` won't work.

You can test this right here in this question page. Run these in Chrome's JavaScript console:

```
// Does nothing
window.open('http://google.com');

// Click anywhere within this page and the new window opens
$(document.body).unbind('click').click(function() { window.open('http://google.com'); });

// This will open a new window, but it would be blank
$(document.body).unbind('click').click(function() { window.open('file:///path/to/a/local/html/file.html'); });
```

You can also test if this works with a local file.  Here's a sample HTML file that simply loads jQuery:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h5>Feel the presha</h5>
        <h3>Come play my game, I'll test ya</h3>
        <h1>Psycho- somatic- addict- insane!</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then open Chrome's JavaScript console and run the statements above. The 3rd one will now work.

Comment: This answer is factually inaccurate. You can run window.open('http://google.com'); by itself and it will open a new window so long as your popup blocker doesn't get in the way.

Comment: Thanks @Deadron...I totally didn't notice my pop-up blocker was what was preventing me from calling window.open() from the chrome console!