# Window.open() blank window

Tags: java, gwt

Good morning, I have developed an application in GWT. I have included the following line in my code:

```
Window.open("file:///"+result, "download_file", "");
```

However, when window is opened, this is a blank window, as the picture:

[image]

I check that result contains the path and name of file. What could the problem be?

Comment: What is the intention of using file URL? You can have downloadable file deployed in your web server and open it as a normal file, right?   `Window.open("<complete path>/"+result, "download_file", "");`

Comment: But file is not in Web Server...

Comment: The issue is with using file URI in Window.open. You cannot open a file(specified using file URL) from a page loaded using HTTP, that is, the GWT page. See this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5011472/open-a-local-html-file-using-window-open-in-chrome) for more info