# js:Window.open() for trying to open local folder failed

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I can not open local file ,meanwhile i use "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-web-security --allow-file-access-from-files on my shortcut of my google chrome.
the explorer tips the security mode had been closed and I can open a new window using js or href attribute.
But the question is :why each time I click the href  ,it always open a blank page and nothing to display.so..

```
function copyUrl(obj)
{
var href = $(obj).attr("hreff");
var hideInput = $("#hidInputHref");
hideInput.val(href);
hideInput.select();
try
{
    document.execCommand('copy');
    var opener = window.open('file:////C:/windows');
   // opener.document.write("<iframe src='c:\' width='100%' height='100%'></iframe>");
    //var test = "<body><script>" +
    //    "alert(1);console.log(1);"
    //"<" + "\/script><div>11111111111</div></body>";

    ////var stateObj = { foo: "bar" };

    //opener.document.write(test);

    //opener.history.pushState("", "page 2", "./a.html");
    //opener.location.href = "www.baidu.com";
    //opener.location.reload();

    opener.opener.location.href = "C:\windows";

}
catch (err)
{
    console.log(err);
}

}
```

C# code:

```
partsQueryList[i].ImageRefLink = "<a onclick='copyUrl(this)' hreff='" + "C:\\" + "' ><font color='blue'>ImageRefLink</font></a>";
```

btw,when I tried to use pushSate method ,it can push a new url to new window,but It can not solve crossdomain issue.so...how could I solve it?thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have 4 slashes instead of 3. Try this :

```
var opener = window.open('file:///C:/windows');
```

Note: Also C:/windows doesn't seem like a valid file. Try with a valid file name.

Check this post for more help : [Open a local HTML file using window.open in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5011472/open-a-local-html-file-using-window-open-in-chrome)

Comment: Hi,I just  want to open  a folder but a  file.