# How to open a local file path in new tab in my browser using javascript?

Tags: javascript

`window.open(URL, '_blank')`

this is not working with local file
it's give error "Not allowed to load local resource"

my local file path is like bellow

file:///var/www/html/proj/proj.pdf

Comment: Yes, you can't do that.  For obvious security reasons.

Comment: as it says its not allowed, depending on what you want you could use a form input and then read the file into a new window or iframe etc https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL

Comment: no, it's now working fine.. i just add http:// and it's working fine... no need to read file and other iframe etc

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple fix and solution for your problem.
Obviously, there are security systems in I assume you are using chrome.

If it's an image, please use: https://imgbb.com
If it's a file such as a folder, text, zipped file, etc. Please use:  https://app.mediafire.com/myfiles OR https://easyupload.io

I hope this answers your question, If the solutions above do not work. Please leave a reply.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's impossible to open local resources via javascript, as it will be considered a security violation to protect users from malicious pages stealing their data. You can flag your browser to allow it. But it won't work in unflagged browsers.

If this question does not solve it, I think it's not possible to do: [Open a local HTML file using window.open in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5011472/open-a-local-html-file-using-window-open-in-chrome)